# Rails assign records to groups evenly at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have models Turn, TurnGroup, TurnTeam and TurnGroupTeam

turn.rb

```
has_many :turn_groups
has_many :turn_teams
```

turn_group.rb

```
belongs_to :turn
has_many :turn_group_teams
```

turn_group_team.rb

```
belongs_to :turn_group
belongs_to :turn_team
```

turn_team.rb

```
belongs_to :turn
has_many :turn_group_teams
```

I am trying to create a method that assigns all turn_teams to turn_groups at once.
So far I did:

```
  def_assign_teams
  @turn_teams = @turn.turn_teams
  @turn_teams.each.do |turn_team|
  TurnGroupTeam.create(turn_team_id: turn_team.id, turn_group_id: ??? )
  end
```

I don't get how to assign turn_group_id. It would be enough something simple like:

```
TurnTeam 1,2,3,4,5,6
TurnGroup A,B 
TurnGroupTeam 1-A, 2-B, 3-A, 4-B, 5-A, 6-B
```

How can I achieve that? Or a method to assign teams to groups randomly and evenly would be even better although not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, it looks like you will want to get all your turn groups

```
def assign_teams

    index = 0
    @turn_teams = @turn.turn_teams
    turn_groups = @turn.turn_groups
    @turn_teams.each do |turn_team|
        TurnGroupTeam.create(turn_team_id: turn_team.id, turn_group_id: turn_groups[index].id )
        if index === turn_groups.count
            index = 0
        else
            index = index + 1
        end
    end
end
```

Something along the above should work,  basically, you are getting all the turn groups in an array of records. after that, you are assigning the turn_groups id based on how many loops have occurred.

Please note,  if you take your above example and add TurnGroup C,D the groups would be uneven (you will have to do a bit of math to ensure even groups)

Hope this helps out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The method works but it stops after first loop. The error is 'NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):' I'm trying to understand the cause, after that I will accept the answer..

Comment: ty for the fixes in the code.  I would attempt to do a "puts turn_groups.inspect" and check the output.